# Cocoa - Core Animation - How to stop proxy animation?

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, nswindow

I have an NSWindow which I fade in from invisible to full opacity, over a custom time, using the **animator** proxy:

```
[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:1.0f]; // Custom timing, 1 sec.
[[myWindow animator] setAlphaValue: 1.0f];
[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

However, if I attempt to set the window's visibility **while** the animation is proceeding, the animation is not stopped. In the following example, the window will briefly appear at 0.5 visibility, but will then continue to animate.

e.g.

```
[myWindow setAlphaValue: 0.5f];  // Animation continues after calling this.
```

**Q. How can I stop the animation?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've got an application that does pretty much this (the menu bar covering window in [Shroud](http://sabi.net/nriley/software/#shroud)) and answering this question I found a bug in it—although my animations are 0.1s so it would probably never be triggered in practice. But thanks. :-)

Animation durations of 0s are special-cased to behave just like setting the alpha value directly, so you can't use them, but you can use a very small duration, something like this, which will create a new animation that supersedes the in-progress one:

```
[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:0.01];
[[myWindow animator] setAlphaValue:0.5];
[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. Yes, I'd just come to the same conclusion about setting a tiny duration, after discovering that 0.0f didn't work. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach is to provide custom animation class (e.g. `CABasicAnimation`) with the `delegate` property by setting the [`animations`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsanimatablepropertycontainer?language=objc) property. Then the corresponding [delegate methods](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caanimation/1412490-delegate?language=objc) can be used to track and manipulate actual animations.