# NSWindow setAlpha not taking effect

Tags: cocoa, macos, animation, nswindow

my app has a window animating it's alpha from 0 to 1 when it becomes active and setting it's alpha to 0 on deactivate, but I'm finding that the alpha isn't set to 0 on deactivate if my app is only activated for a very short time (< 1 second).

So the effect is that the window just quickly blinks into view before disappearing and then fading in.

It's almost as if it doesn't get to set it's alpha to 0 on deactivate because the window never finished animating it to 1 when it was activated.

How can I force the alpha to 0? - Setting it to 0 at the beginning of applicationWillBecomeActive doesn't work....

Here's the code:

```
- (void)applicationWillBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
    [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:0.10]; 
    [[mainPanel animator] setAlphaValue:1.0f];
    [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];       
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [mainPanel setAlphaValue:0.0];
    [mainPanel orderOut:nil];   
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocoa - Core Animation - How to stop proxy animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048573/cocoa-core-animation-how-to-stop-proxy-animation)